# Do I need to claim baggage for customs at ICN layover?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, international-travel, icn

My daughter is traveling from DFW to LAX then LAX to ICN (Incheon, Korea) then from ICN to ULN (Mongolia).

Does she need to pick up baggage at ICN to recheck in for ULN and how long is the process to recheck-in at ICN?

Comment: Is it the same ticket?

Comment: If this is urgent, you'd be much better off ringing your airline to ask, rather than relying on random people on the internet!